# Exchange 2013 Autdiscover request from other user

Tags: exchange-2013, outlook-2010, autodiscovery

Scenario:

Test environment with Exchange 2013 servers, 1 mbx server, 1 cas server. 
Autodiscover configured. This environment is mainly for learning/testing purposes.

Lets say I have 3 users.

```
user1
user2
user3
```

I am logged in as user1, using my Outlook 2010 client to connect to the Exchange 2013 on-premises servers, with the use of Autodiscover.

Now, user2 and user3 have shared their calendar's.
User1 is viewing the calendar of user2 and user3.

Now once in a while I get the autodiscover message:

> Allow this website to configure **user2@domain.com** server settings?
>
> https:\\autodiscover.domain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml

This message (not my picture):

[image]

Why is it, that I am logged in as **User1** but receiving the autodiscover message for **user2**, but not for **user3**? I am viewing both their calendar's.

Does one understand this behavior? Some explanation would be appreciated very much.

Comment: Followed the test by the given link. Autodiscover does not give any errors.

Comment: Bump. Anyone..?

Comment: @Diamant We periodically see the same thing and it does appear to be directly related to shared calendars

Answer (score 0):

The autodiscovery process launches a non-SSL request first (`http://`) and then gets redirected to SSL (`302` to `https://`). This redirection triggers the popup, unfortunately.

This behaviour is even documented here: [KB2480582](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2480582/how-to-suppress-the-autodiscover-redirect-warning-in-outlook), although the proposed solution is insane. Also, switching discovery to HTTP ain't a good solution too. It's not secure and also Outlook will ignore the discovery result if it's served over non-SSL connection :)

A better solution could be to disable the redirection from non-SSL to SSL. This can be achieved in several ways:

1. I use KEMP LB for my Exchange and was able to modify the HTTP redirect service to exclude any `/\/autodiscover.*/` requests. Basically, you open the HTTP redirect service, create a new `SubVS`, assign to it an existing `Autodiscover_#` rule or create your own based on the regexp above (case insensitive!) and configure `SubVS > Not Available Redirection Handling` to `Error 404`. This pretty much works.
2. If your load balancer is not up to this task, you may alternatively split the `autodiscover.yourdomain` to a different IP and serve HTTPS only on this address.

There are possibly many other ways to achieve this. Anyways, once `http://autodiscover.yourdomain` is not producing any result (or is not reachable) Outlook itself tries HTTPS over the same domain and everything works.